# How to avoid audio clipping when using SAY command in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, audio, speech

When "say" command is used in AppleScript it seems the audio channel is asleep because the beginning of the word always gets clipped. Subsequent words are find but after a few minutes the audio channel goes into some hibernation mode and the problem happens again. I've tried various things with various success such as:

```
say "?"
say "something"
```

But still the result is not good. Has anyone come up with a solution to this problem?

Comment: Works fine for me on **macOS Catalina** using a 2019 **MacBook Pro**. What version of **macOS** are you running and on what _model_ of **Mac**?

Comment: I'm running bigsur on 2017 macbook pro but this problem has been around for as long as I remember. You just don't notice if it you've previously used the audio interface. If you wait a few minutes without using it and just issue command like:

```
say "something"
```
This s will get clipped off.

Comment: All I can tell you is that on three different **Macs** I have never had the `say` _command_ cut any part of the starring _character/word_ off the _statement_ when running on physical hardware. That said, I have in virtual machines experienced a truncation, but that never surprised me. If from a clean boot, having done nothing else but tested a `say` _command_, is the issue reproducible under that expressed condition? Note that when preforming the test you've allowed appropriate time for the boot/login process to fully complete.

Comment: BTW I often use the `say` _command_ in both **AppleScript** _scripts_ and _shell scripts_. So, as often as I do, I'm sure I would have noticed an issue such as this as it would annoy me too.

Comment: I will test it but what is necessary to reproduce it is to not use the audio for at least a few minutes. I've noticed it for at least the past 10 years on every mac I've had. It doesn't cut off much but it's enough to notice. Just clips the first micro second but only does it the first time. Any subsequent audio is perfect until there is another few minute pause.

Comment: I had this when I connected the optical sound output from my MBP to an amp. It seems that the connection drops after a few seconds of no sound output, and then takes a moment to reconnect, cutting off the start of any sound (such as speech). I never found a solution; but a good workaround is to switch to a USB audio interface, which doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the problem. I'm using an app called Boom 2 and that was causing the initial clipping.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.